# Search occurrences of a string in a TextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a textview with a large text, and I would like to find all the occurrences of a string (search) inside it and every time i press search scroll the textView to the range of the current occurrence.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do a forward search on text view, use the following snippet -

```
NSRange textRange;
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [textView.text length]);

textRange = [textView.text rangeOfString:searchString 
                                 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                   range:searchRange];

if ( textRange.location == NSNotFound ) {
    // Not there
} else {
    textView.selectedRange = textRange;
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:textRange];
}
```

Basically we use the `NSString`s [`rangeOfString:options:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3aoptions%3arange%3a) method to find the text and then highlight the text using [`selectedRange`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/selectedRange) and make it visible using [`scrollRangeToVisible:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextView/scrollRangeToVisible%3a).

Now once found you can find the next occurrence by modifying the search range.

```
if ( textRange.location + textRange.length <= [textView.text length] ) {
    searchRange.location = textRange.location + textRange.length;
    searchRange.length = [textView.text length] - searchRange.location;

    textRange = [textView.text rangeOfString:searchString 
                                     options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                       range:searchRange];

    /* Validate search result & highlight the text */
} else {
    // No more text to search.
}
```

You can also search backwards by declaring

```
searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, textRange.location);
```

and then passing `(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSBackwardsSearch)` in the `options`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I get home